# reinitiating semaphores in java

Tags: java, synchronization, semaphore, java.util.concurrent

i want to use semaphores to control the cars' crossing on a bridge, i have cars coming from east and cars from west.
i must give each side a fixed amount of time, then switch to the other side. i used two semaphores, one for each side, i let the bridge initiate them with zero permits.

`east_semaphore = new Semaphore(0);`

`west_semaphore = new Semaphore(0);`

then re-initiate one of them with 1 permit.

`east_semaphore = new Semaphore(1);`

then after the time passes it re-initiate both of them setting the permits for the first to zero and for the second to one.

`east_semaphore = new Semaphore(0);`

`west_semaphore = new Semaphore(1);`

the problem is that some objects already asked to acquire the semaphores before re-initiating them. and i think their requests are lost after re-initiating.

the cars from east keep acquire  and release the semaphore, and i need to force the semaphore release in order to acquire it and release the other semaphore of the west side to let the cars pass from west.

how can i solve this. is their a way instead of re-initiating?

Comment: If you start with semaphore "A" that an object interacts with, then you create a new semaphore "B" – by doing something like `east_semaphore = new Semaphore(0)` – then that first object will not know anything about the new semaphore B. It isn't clear what problem you're actually trying to solve, but I would encourage you to take a step back and re-think your approach.

Comment: you are right. i am creating new object. that's why i need another way to force semaphore releasing (if there is any). 
or any other idea that can help

Comment: You only need one semaphore for this.

Comment: Create one semaphore with the maximum number of permits that you need, and acquire all that you don't want to have available right now. If you want to increase the number of available permits, release some. But don't change the reference to the semaphore object - best to make the field `final`.